# Mounting TV on Faux Veneer

Tags: mounting, television

I just bought a house that has a stone fireplace but the facing was actually covered up with faux veneer. I want to hang up my 65 inch TV on it, how would I go about that?  any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: TV over fireplace is a bad idea, unless you never light the fireplace

Comment: Fireplace is non working.  The original owners have a stone fireplace which they covered up with theis stone veneer.

Answer (score 4):

Bad idea overall to mount a TV up high over a fireplace. Just do a search here and you will find many answers discouraging this for a multitude of reasons. Key among the reasons is based upon the fact the best viewing of a TV is pretty much straight onto its screen. In addition, for your physical health the best viewing position is sitting and looking straight ahead rather than trying to stare up at an angle.

I have heard folks say that they have regretted ever having hung a TV up over a fireplace. Do yourself a favor and get a TV console with an inbuilt mount post at the back to which you can attach your tilt TV bracket. Enjoy the convenience of being able to move the whole thing around when a decision is made to reorganize the room layout, change furniture or you are sick of the TV location. You will also be glad you did not do a big disfigurement of the faux veneer around your fireplace unit.

Comment: I agree that it's bad to mount a TV over a fireplace for various reasons but the fact is, people arrange their living rooms around the fireplace and most living rooms are not big enough to accommodate multiple focal points with different arrangements of furniture.   As bad as it is to do this, it is what people do.   Most people, as far as I can tell 99% of people.   So the least we can do is help them implement their unergonomic plans safely.

Comment: yup small living room with limited options for tv mounting.

Answer (score 1):

Start out by marking in pencil exactly where the TV bracket will be installed. I'd try to remove the veneer where the bracket mounts to the wall so you can see what you'll be drilling into and to make it a more solid fit. Get the required number of lag shields, lag screws and the proper size drill bit if they are not included in the mounting bracket packaging. A hammer drill would be helpful too. Drill your holes in the brick/stone avoiding any mortar lines. Then shove the lag shields into the holes and attach the bracket with the lag screws.

Answer (score 1):

You need to better understand what's behind that veneer.  You say it's a "stone fireplace".  What exactly does that mean and how do you know?   Is there solid stone behind that veneer, from floor to ceiling?  Sometimes you'll find that the stone (or brick) construction recedes away from the wall as you get nearer the ceiling and you have studs and drywall at the upper portion of the wall above the fireplace.  You need to know.  That might mean removing some of the brick facing, or drilling a bunch of test holes.   Without knowing, you can't mount anything.

You say the veneer is "faux".  What does that mean?  It it plastic?  Is it wafer thin?  Is it poorly glued to the wall behind it?  There is something going on every 12 rows in your photo.  It could be that those are just big fake plastic tiles 12 rows high, or it could be thin bricks laid nicely with structural support every 12 rows.   Do you know?

Comment: PS I second the advice that mounting a TV above a fireplace is ergonomically and aesthetically poor ... but that's not your question so I'll keep it out of my answer.

Comment: i have seen pictures of what the place looked like before so i know there is the original stone fireplace behind the veneer.   the veneer is not plastic feels like stone but not really... anyway, sounds like my question gave you heartburn, so we'll just leave it there,